# bootstrap.yml not loading in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm experiencing a problem when starting a spring boot client application that needs to connect to the configuration server. The bootstrap.yml file is being ignored

Configuration Server - This works!

```yaml
server:
  port: 8888  
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org/eco/properties.git
```

`bootstrap.yml` - Config Client - Not working!

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: api
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

**The file bootstrap.yml is being ignored when starting the application**.

POM Client

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-cloud.version>2.0.0.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Database dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>api-emissor</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main class client

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("br.com.eco.api.emissor")
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.eco.api.emissor.repository")
@EntityScan("br.com.eco.api.emissor.domain")
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Why is the bootstrap.yml being ignored?**

Comment: You can't mix versions of spring cloud. You are using an old version of spring cloud Netflix eureka

Comment: Do you think this could be my problem?

Comment: Maybe, but until you have valid versions, I can't tell.

Answer (score 43):

Add this dependency in Spring Boot config client:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I only discovered my application was not reading my bootstrap by using truss on my application.  This suggestion fixed the issue.

Comment: This one is really fixing the issue on my side. Not the spring-cloud-starter one.

Comment: It seems this one is only available for Spring cloud version 3 or higher https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap

Comment: For me fine, with springboot 2.7.0, but using gradle not mvn, I added: `implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'`

Answer (score 18):

You need to add dependency for spring cloud starter.

Comment: I take it nothing worked.

Answer (score 4):

You must add this dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a config name and it must match the config file name on the configuration service.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      name: myService    # myService.yml or myService-[profile].yml( if you have a profile activated).
        uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The pom.xml i used specified the files it includes from src/main/resources. So i also had to add the bootstrap.properties here:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                    <include>bootstrap.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
...</build>
```

Comment: Encountering the same scenario, along with additional information: by default, the parent POM is 'spring-boot-starter-parent,' which copies everything in the 'resources' directory to the classpath. If you are using a custom parent POM, being careful with this

Answer (score 2):

If you defined a `spring.config.location` it will override all paths to the configurations files including the path to `bootstrap.yml` so you have to change `spring.config.location` to `spring.config.additional-location`.

So when you launch your app you'll have to add `-Dspring.config.additional-location=/path/to/application.yml`.

For more info check [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-location)

Answer (score 2):

Application will use `bootstrap.yml` in case when it uses some spring-cloud dependencies. That can be **cloud discovery client**:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or **cloud config client**:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I using STS4 and the produced POM file by default doesn't work and I hade the same problem like you, but after I changed a little bit in my POM file, everything is working and finally I found something like "Fetching config from server at" in my console.
The changes in my POM were as follows:

1. Change the spring boot version to 2.2.6.RELEASE.
2. Change the spring cloud version to Hoxton.SR6 Or Hoxton.SR4 (and I believe any
   Hoxton version will work).

After I applied the previous changes, My POM file looks like:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.0</version> -->
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.kha.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>limits-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>limits-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot - Cloud</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        
        <!-- <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version> -->
        <!-- <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-M4</spring-cloud.version> -->
        
        <!--  Both are working with spring boot version 2.2.6.RELEASE 
              you should find something like "Fetching config from server at" in your console 
              each time you run the client project as spring boot app 
        -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
        <!-- <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version> -->    
    </properties>
```