# Application not taking spring.cloud.config.* properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a client application which is trying to access the a config application using a `bootstrap.yml` file

my `bootstrap.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: app
  profiles: local
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      uri: http://localhost:9999
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appDb
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

but when i run the application it has no problem taking the DB config , here is my main class

```java
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @RefreshScope
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    public class OtaApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(OtaApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

also i also have the `spring-boot-cloud` dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

command i run for the application

```
java -jar target/app.jar --spring.profiles.active=local --spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml
```

**Note :** i have also tried with the absolute path

when i run
`curl http://localhost:9999/app/local`
i'm able to fetch my properties

but the application is not taking the config from the config-server.(and yes the config-server does have `@EnableConfigServer` enabled)

so my question is why is it not taking the config properties from the config server??

is there some error that i'm not able to catch??

> previously referred questions :
>
> [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821110/bootstrap-yml-not-loading-in-spring-boot-2) [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016868/spring-cloud-config-client-not-loading-configuration-from-config-server) [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715682/bootstrap-yml-not-loading-for-spring-boot-2)

Comment: Use `classpath:bootstrap.yml` insetad of `src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml` or remove the parameter totally as that is already the default config location.

Comment: i tried that as well, to no avail

Comment: Why are you setting the location at all?

Comment: @spencergibb it's a test , as in production we will be using location , this might not be the best case example but it's has it's reasons

Comment: Try `--spring.cloud.bootstrap.location=src/main/resources/`

Comment: @spencergibb same issue